# counter value is getting rested in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to print odd number in one thread and even number in another. I tried creating two thread and printing it in run method.

```
public class OddEven
{
    private final int MAX = 10;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private volatile boolean isOdd = true;

    public synchronized void printEven(int counter)
    {
        try {
            if (!isOdd) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + counter);
                counter++;
                isOdd = true;
            }
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void printOdd(int counter)
    {
        if (isOdd) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + counter);
            isOdd = false;
        }
        notifyAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OddEven oddEven = new OddEven();

        Thread th1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (OddEven.counter < oddEven.MAX) {
                    oddEven.printEven(OddEven.counter);
                }
            }
        };
        th1.setName("even -");
        th1.start();

        Thread th2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (OddEven.counter < oddEven.MAX) {
                    oddEven.printOdd(OddEven.counter);
                }
            }
        };
        th2.setName("odd -");
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

But it is printing it like below infinitely.

```
even - 0
odd - 1
even - 0
odd - 1
even - 0
odd - 1
```

Comment: Try to use AtomicInterger

Comment: (Completely irrelevant, but `isOdd` need not be `volatile` as it is only accessed when synchronized)

Answer (score 2):

To read: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1)

1. You pass in a primitive. `counter++;` makes sense only within the method and has no impact on the outer world. `count` refers to the method param, not to the field `this.count`.
2. There is no proper synchronisation placed upon the condition `OddEven.counter < oddEven.MAX`, so different things may happen.

My advice would be to remove `isOdd` and do a check on the spot. For instance,

```
public synchronized void printEven() {
    if (counter % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + ++counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using and modifying an instance variable of a class. This is not the issue.

Comment: @Matthew that's the issue, a method param hides the field, so he isn't modifying the field.

Answer (score 0):

The line `oddEven.printEven(OddEven.counter)` passes an integer by value to the `printEven` method which does not change the value of `OddEven.counter` when it does `counter++` as also pointed in other answers here.

To get the desired output, one option is to remove the passed parameter to both `printEven` and `printOdd` methods. And there are many other ways to achieve what you are trying to do here.

And there is also a mistake in the `printEven` method. `counter++;` needs to be before the print statement.

This will give you the desired output.